# HTML/CSS vertical divider with bullets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was just wondering how I can obtain this kind of UI design using HTML/CSS:

[image]

It should be that every time a user inputs a new data, it'll display the data with a divider and a bullet.

I am new to these kind of UI design in terms of HTML/CSS.

Comment: show us a snippet of code, then we can help you moving forward. User plunker or codepen to show live example.

Comment: have you tried borders and pseudoselectors?

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: @madalinivascu not yet. what would you suggest I use?

Comment: @SenJacob still researching on codepen on where to start

Comment: @Terence border left and :before/after

Comment: @Smit Will take note of that! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty darn close.. Only things I can think of are that you will need to tweak the fixed sizes for your font and that it is probably not going to be pretty on a mobile device. https://jsfiddle.net/x6bthxgw/

HTML:

```css
/* CSS:  */

    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    ul.pretty-list {
      border-left: 1px solid grey;
      padding-left: 16px;
      margin-left: 200px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    ul.pretty-list li {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    ul.pretty-list ul {
      padding-left: 0px;
    }
    
    ul.pretty-list h4 {
      color: skyblue;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    ul.pretty-list .date {
      margin-left:-216px;
      width:184px;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 1em;
      float: left;
      position:relative;
    }
    
    ul.pretty-list .date:after {
      content:"•";
      position: absolute;
      right:-10px;
      width:21px;
      font-size:30px;
      line-height:18px;
      text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="pretty-list">
      <li>
          <h4><div class="date">2015 - Present</div>Item 1</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
            <li>Subitem 3</li>
            <li>Subitem 4</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
          <h4><div class="date">2014 - 2015</div>Item 2</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
            <li>Subitem 3</li>
            <li>Subitem 4</li>
          </ul>
      </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the snippet below. I dont know for certain if is this what you need. This CSS is written on simple logic:

```css
.full-width {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 display:flex;
}
.first_box {
 width:300px;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:right;
 font-size:15px;
 padding-right:15px;
}
.second_box {
 width:400px;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:left;
 padding-left:30px;
 font-size:15px;
 border-left:2px solid #069;
 position:relative;
}
.second_box:after {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 left:-8px;
 top:8px;
 background:#900;
 width:15px;
 height:15px;
 border-radius:50%;
}
.second_box h2 , .first_box h2 {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
 <div class="first_box">
     <h2>2015 present</h2>
    </div><!-- /.first_box -->
    <div class="second_box">
     <h2>frontend web Developer</h2>
        <p>something here</p>
        <p>something here</p>
        <p>something here</p>
        
    </div><!-- /.second_box -->
</div><!-- /.full-width -->
<div class="full-width">
 <div class="first_box">
     <h2>2015 present</h2>
    </div><!-- /.first_box -->
    <div class="second_box">
     <h2>frontend web Developer</h2>
        <p>something here</p>
        <p>something here</p>
        <p>something here</p>
        
    </div><!-- /.second_box -->
</div><!-- /.full-width -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It is a simple structure to follow.

```
    <div class="abc">
      <div class="abc3">
        <div class="abc2">
          2016 - Present
          <span class="abc1"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="abc2">
          Front End Developer
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="abc3">
       <div class="abc2"></div>
       <div class="abc2"></div>
     </div>
   </div>


<style>
.abc{
    display: table;
    background: grey;
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}
.abc1{
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    right: -42px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.abc2 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
.abc3{
   display: table-row;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the code below:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <span class="text-left">2015-Present</span>
      <span class="bullet"></span>
      <span class="text-right">Developer</span>
  </li>
  <li>
     <span class="text-left">2015-Present</span>
     <span class="bullet"></span>
     <span class="text-right">Developer</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="text-left">2015-Present</span>
    <span class="bullet"></span>
    <span class="text-right">Developer</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
  ul {
        list-style: none;
        width: 300px;
    }

    ul li {
        position: relative;
    }

    ul li span {
        width: calc(100%/3);
        display: inline-block;
    }

    ul li:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 107px;
        height: 90%;
        width: 2px;
        background: #cccccc;
    }

    .bullet {
        width: 7px;
        height: 7px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .text-left {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .text-right {
        text-align: right
    }
```

Please arrange positions and text according to the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with the below link: 
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/spankajd/cttxt2ra/)

```
<div style="
    display: table;
    background: yellow;
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
"><div style="
    display: table-row;
"><div style="
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
">2015 - Present<span style="
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    right: -42px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 50%;
"></span></div><div style="
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
">Front End Developer</div></div><div style="
    display: table-row;
"><div style="
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
"></div><div style="
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
"></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    menu1
  </li>
  <li>
    menu2
  </li>
  <li>
    menu3
  </li>
</ul>
```